# How do you install Alex on Haskell Platform?

Tags: haskell, alex

I have Haskell Platform 8.2.2 installed on Windows. When I run `ghci` and type `alex H.x` after `Prelude>`, I get

```
<interactive>:3:6: error:
    Not in scope: `H.x'
    No module named `H' is imported.
```

When I type just `alex`, I get

```
<interactive>:6:1: error:
    * Variable not in scope: alex
    * Perhaps you meant `lex' (imported from Prelude).
```

I looked in `Haskell Platform\8.2.2\lib` and I can see a folder called `Cabal-2.0.1.0` but nothing for `alex`.

How do I get Alex installed?

Answer (score 2):

`alex` is an executable program, to be run from command line, not a library to be invoked from GHCi.

To run `alex` via `stack` (which is what you have installed), type:

```
stack exec alex H.x
```

(assuming you actually have a file named `H.x` lying around)

The first time you run it like this, `stack` will build `alex`, which will take a few minutes. This will happen one time only, subsequent runs will be quick.

If you want to run `alex` without `stack`, you can ask `stack` to put `alex` on your `PATH`. To do that, type:

```
stack install alex
```

After that, you can execute `alex` without prepending `stack exec` every time:

```
alex H.x
```